# Dubai Transit Visa

Tags: visas

Travelling Round-trip by Emirates, BKK-FARO,BKK, do I deed Dubai Transit Visa only for staying airside of DXB for 6.5 hours as a citizen of Myanmar ?

Answer (score 1):

No you do not.

There are no visa formalities for transit requirements at Dubai.

As you are on one ticket by Emirates you don't need to leave Terminal 3 and your luggage will be checked through.

Enjoy your time at the airport transit area, there are many things to do.